# BottomNavigatorBar with 5 items icons : equal space/width (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar

How to have equal width/space between 5 icons in a BottomNavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have equal width between icons, we have to set the type of BottomNavigationBar :

```
type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed
```

It will be set automatically to BottomNavigationBarType.shifting if there is more than 3 items